# How to tell pgfplots to keep empty "series"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a plot with `xticklabels` defined as symbolic.

In a modified version of my plot, I want to set `ymin` value. When doing this, my plot is automatically updated: all x series having only points which y value is below this new ymin are removed. How can I change this behavior ?

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={X0, X1, X2, X3},
    xtick=data,
    grid=major,
    only marks
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(X0,0) (X1,1) (X2,2) (X3,3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={X0, X1, X2, X3},
    xtick=data,
    grid=major,
    only marks,
    ymin=1
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(X0,0) (X1,1) (X2,2) (X3,3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result. On the second graph I would like to have X0 xtick label visible even if it's point is not.

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean that you still want a legend entry for the series even though none of its points are visible in the plot? What's the relevance of the `xticklabels from table` that you mentioned? Do you have a case where the x tick labels are affected by a `ymin` value?

Comment: I added a working example to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be clearly specified in the manual, but you can get the desired result by specifying `xmin=X0` and `enlarge x limits=true`.  Without the latter, `X0` will lie on the y axis, i.e. there will no space to the left of `X0`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={X0, X1, X2, X3},
    xtick=data,
    grid=major,
    only marks,
    ymin=1,
    xmin=X0,enlarge x limits=true
    ]
    \addplot coordinates {(X0,0) (X1,1) (X2,2) (X3,3)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the general case you will also want to specify `xmax` to capture all your data points.